# Value error at /register/ Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to encode the payload data of a form I created using react from frontend using the code below

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const encryptedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
      formData.password,
      "b'VFRkU0hHSEZORFN2dWx1b3VNT213SVE4OTJkLWFiYU1CQU5TdjVGWjhiST0'"
    ).toString();

    const encryptedPassword2 = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
      formData.password2,
      "b'VFRkU0hHSEZORFN2dWx1b3VNT213SVE4OTJkLWFiYU1CQU5TdjVGWjhiST0'"
    ).toString();

    const encryptedEmail = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
      formData.email,
      "b'VFRkU0hHSEZORFN2dWx1b3VNT213SVE4OTJkLWFiYU1CQU5TdjVGWjhiST0'"
    ).toString();

    const encryptedPayload = {
      ...formData,
      password: encryptedPassword,
      password2: encryptedPassword2,
      email: encryptedEmail,
    };

    // Send the encrypted payload to the backend
    axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:8003/register/", encryptedPayload)
      .then((response) => {
        // Handle successful response
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle error
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
```

So whenever I submit the form, the view function below is what I used to decrypt the payload and save it to the database.

```
class CreateUser(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        encrypted_password = request.data.get("password")
        encrypted_password2 = request.data.get("password2")
        encrypted_email = request.data.get("email")
        encryption_secret_key = "b'VFRkU0hHSEZORFN2dWx1b3VNT213SVE4OTJkLWFiYU1CQU5TdjVGWjhiST0'"

        cipher_suite = Fernet(encryption_secret_key)
        decrypted_password = cipher_suite.decrypt(
            encrypted_password.encode()).decode()
        decrypted_password2 = cipher_suite.decrypt(
            encrypted_password2.encode()).decode()
        decrypted_email = cipher_suite.decrypt(
            encrypted_email.encode()).decode()

        # Update the request data with the decrypted password
        request.data["password"] = decrypted_password
        request.data["pasword2"] = decrypted_password2
        request.data["email"] = decrypted_email
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            user.email = user.email.lower()
            user.username = user.email.lower() if user.email else None
            user.first_name = user.first_name.lower() if user.first_name else None
            user.last_name = user.last_name.lower() if user.last_name else None
            user.avatar = user.avatar if user.avatar else None
            if user.first_name and user.last_name:
                random_string = generate_random_string()
                slug = slugify(
                    f"{user.first_name} {user.last_name} {random_string}")
                while User.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists():
                    random_string = generate_random_string()
                    slug = slugify(
                        f"{user.first_name} {user.last_name} {random_string}"
                    )

                user.slug = slug
            user.set_password(request.data["password"])
            user.password2 = None
            user.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

However, whenever i submit the form and i check the response in the network tab of developer tools. I get the error below

```
Exception Type: ValueError at /register/
Exception Value: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.
```

So how solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encryption secret key that you are using should be URl-safe-base64-encoded string that is 32 bytes long, you can generate new one with this part of code:

```py
import base64
import os

encryption_secret_key = os.urandom(32)  # Generate a random 32-byte key
encryption_secret_key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(encryption_secret_key).decode()

print(encryption_secret_key)
```

and replace it with your hard-coded `encryption_secret_key`

Frontend:

```js
const encryptionSecretKey = "GENERATED_ENCRYPTION_SECRET_KEY";

// ...

const encryptedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
  formData.password,
  encryptionSecretKey
).toString();

const encryptedPassword2 = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
  formData.password2,
  encryptionSecretKey
).toString();

const encryptedEmail = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
  formData.email,
  encryptionSecretKey
).toString();
```

Backend:

```py
encryption_secret_key = "GENERATED_ENCRYPTION_SECRET_KEY"
```

Comment: When i fixed the issue and i tried submitting the form, i get the error *InvalidToken at /register/* *No exception message supplied*

Comment: @Olasubomi This error happens when the ciphertext being decrypted is not valid or when the encryption key used for decryption does not match the key used for encryption.